# WCF REST service streaming JSON objects

Tags: json, rest, wcf, stream, windows-services

I need a windows service in which the REST API dumps a bunch of JSON objects into a stream (content-type: application/stream+json).

Example response (not array of objects):

```
{ id: 1, name: "name 1" }
{ id: 2, name: "name 2" }
{ id: 3, name: "name 3" }
{ id: 4, name: "name 4" }
```

It is possible doing this in WCF REST? Or maybe I should try something other?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/feature-details/how-to-enable-streaming

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a few days I found a solution of my case. First I was modify App.config file and add binding configuration to the endpoint that allow streamed response. Next, operation of service contract must have return Stream. Then in implementation of service contract I set outgoing response content type to "application/stream+json", serialize all objects using DataContractJsonSerializer and write to MemoryStream. At the end I was set position of MemoryStream to zero and then return that stream.

Sample code bellow.

App.config:

```
<system.serviceModel>
  <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" />
  <services>
    <service name="WinService.WcfService">
      <endpoint address="" binding="webHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="webHttpBindingStreamedResponse" contract="WinService.IWcfService" behaviorConfiguration="webHttp" />
      <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange" />
    </service>
  </services>
  <bindings>
    <webHttpBinding>
      <binding name="webHttpBindingStreamedResponse" transferMode="StreamedResponse" maxReceivedMessageSize="67108864"/>
    </webHttpBinding>
  </bindings>
  <behaviors>
    <serviceBehaviors>
      <behavior>
        <!-- To avoid disclosing metadata information, 
        set the values below to false before deployment -->
        <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="True" httpsGetEnabled="True" />
        <!-- To receive exception details in faults for debugging purposes, 
        set the value below to true.  Set to false before deployment 
        to avoid disclosing exception information -->
        <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="True" />
      </behavior>
    </serviceBehaviors>
    <endpointBehaviors>
      <behavior name="webHttp">
        <webHttp />
      </behavior>
    </endpointBehaviors>
  </behaviors>
</system.serviceModel>
```

ServiceContract:

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface IWcfService
{
  [OperationContract]
  [WebGet(UriTemplate = "/stream/{param}", ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)]
  Stream GetJsonStreamedObjects(string param);
}
```

Implementation of ServiceContract:

```
[ServiceBehavior(InstanceContextMode = InstanceContextMode.PerCall)]
[AspNetCompatibilityRequirements(RequirementsMode = AspNetCompatibilityRequirementsMode.Allowed)]
public class WcfService : IWcfService
{
  public Stream GetJsonStreamedObjects(string param)
  {
    var stream = new MemoryStream();
    var serializer = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(JsonObjectDataContract));

    WebOperationContext.Current.OutgoingResponse.ContentType = "application/stream+json";

    foreach (JsonObjectDataContract jsonObjectDataContract in Repository.GetJsonObjectDataContracts(param))
    {
      serializer.WriteObject(stream, jsonObjectDataContract);
    }
    stream.Position = 0;
    return stream;
  }
}
```